# How to install vinyl plank on uneven surfaces in open concept home having tile and carpet?

Tags: tile, vinyl-flooring, vinyl-siding, leveling

The idea is to have a continuous vinyl plank floor in a home that has tile in the dining room and kitchen area, and carpet in the living room (see the image below).
[image]
My intention is:

- To remove the carpet and install the vinyl on the subfloor.
- To keep the tile and install the vinyl on top without removing the tile.

The issue is that when the living room and the tile area meet, there will be a difference in elevation. How do you fix this without adding Transition Strip T Molding?
Is there some wood that changes elevation gradually?

Comment: I would raise the sub floor under the carpet to the tile top.  There is thin under layment up to thick sheets of sub floor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are **looking for** is called "subfloor leveler" [image] which is a tapered material going between subfloor and vinyl

What you probably **want to do** is to have absolutely flat flooring. Remove carpet and "bump up" subfloor with 3/4in plywood or other compatible material to match tile height. Basically, in figure below replace "hardwood" with appropriate OSB/plywood.

[image]

Comment: I didn't understand how the second photo was needed. Would the incline caused by the sub-floor leveler affect the durability of the vinyl plank?

Comment: Also the other issue, is I try to bump the entire sub-floor will cost a lot as it will be the entire 1600 sq feet floor.

Comment: @wondim its for you to decide cost/benefit. I prefer having flat flooring for the next 10 years

Comment: Planks/tiles usually do not like changes in height of a floor.  They can usually be okay for a couple of 16ths in small sections.  If raising the sub floor is too much, then a transition will be better.  Have you pulled up the carpet at the edge to see the difference?